# Attribute values needs to come in pdf while doing DITA to PDF conversion in oxygen

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, dita

My input xml is having lot of metadata information's,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "com.rsicms.rsuite_te:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title outputclass="title">LANDING GEARLANDING GEAR</title>
   <titlealts>
      <navtitle>FUNCTION, DATA FOR PLANS AND DESCRIPTION</navtitle>
   </titlealts>
   <prolog>
      <metadata>
         <data-about>
            <data type="data.module.code">HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</data>
            <data type="classification">01</data>
            <data type="responsible.partner.company">F0302</data>
            <data type="originator">F0302</data>
            <data type="applicability">ALL</data>
            <data type="data.module.reference.code">TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</data>
            <data type="quality.assurance">tabtop</data>
            <data type="skill.level">sk01</data>
            <data type="reason.for.update">First Release</data>
            <data type="publication.code">UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</data>
         </data-about>
         <foreign outputclass="issuenum">001</foreign>
         <unknown outputclass="date">2016-01-29</unknown>
      </metadata>
   </prolog>
   <body>
      <section>
         <title>DESCRIPTION</title>
         <p>The A380 is available with two types of turbofan engines, the
Rolls-Royce Trent 900 (variants A380-841, −842 and −843F) or the Engine
Alliance GP7000 (A380-861 and −863F).  Noise reduction was an important
requirement in the A380 design, and particularly affects engine design.</p>
         <p>Landing gears<ul>
               <li>
                  <p>Nose Landing Gear</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Wing Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 4 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Body Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 6 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
         <p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Body Landing Gear</title>
         <p>The two body landing gears have a six-wheel bogie
beam and a leg assembly that includes an oleo- pneumatic shock absorber.
A two-piece drag-stay assembly mechanically locks the leg in the extended
position.</p>
         <fig>
            <title>Landing gear</title>
            <image align="center" href="../ICN-HSXWB-A-791111-H-F0302-00001-A-001-01.tif"/>
         </fig>
      </section>
   </body>
</topic>
```

the above meta information is coming in pdf as like below

[dita to pdf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfY9v.png)

I used the xslt as below:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/data ')]">
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="data">
            <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="data-about/data">
       <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
<xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="data__label">
                <xsl:call-template name="insertVariable">
                    <xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="'Data'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </fo:inline>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

I want the pdf output has to be like with attribute value of meta data colon then the information,

```
data.module.code: HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D
classification: 01
responsible.partner.company: F0302
.
.
.
```

Like wise i need. Please help anybody on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given your input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <title outputclass="title">LANDING GEARLANDING GEAR</title>
    <titlealts>
        <navtitle>FUNCTION, DATA FOR PLANS AND DESCRIPTION</navtitle>
    </titlealts>
    <prolog>
        <metadata>
            <data-about>
                <data type="data.module.code">HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</data>
                <data type="classification">01</data>
                <data type="responsible.partner.company">F0302</data>
                <data type="originator">F0302</data>
                <data type="applicability">ALL</data>
                <data type="data.module.reference.code">TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</data>
                <data type="quality.assurance">tabtop</data>
                <data type="skill.level">sk01</data>
                <data type="reason.for.update">First Release</data>
                <data type="publication.code">UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</data>
            </data-about>
            <foreign outputclass="issuenum">001</foreign>
            <unknown outputclass="date">2016-01-29</unknown>
        </metadata>
    </prolog>
</root>
```

(Note that I added the `root` element.)

**Using this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="metadata/*[position() > 1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <fo:block>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@outputclass, ':')"/>
            </b>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', current())"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data-about/*">
        <fo:block>
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(@type, ':')"/>
            </b>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', current())"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Results in:**

```
<fo:block><b>data.module.code:</b> HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>classification:</b> 01</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>responsible.partner.company:</b> F0302</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>originator:</b> F0302</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>applicability:</b> ALL</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>data.module.reference.code:</b> TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>quality.assurance:</b> tabtop</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>skill.level:</b> sk01</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>reason.for.update:</b> First Release</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>publication.code:</b> UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>issuenum:</b> 001</fo:block>
<fo:block><b>date:</b> 2016-01-29</fo:block>
```

Hopefully this helps!

EDIT: Edited the XSLT as an answer to OP's comment.

EDIT2: Changed XSLT once more due to remarks made by OP.

Comment: Thanks Fluazinam. Its working. But i need the break between each element. I got the output like 
data.module.code : HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D classification : 01 responsible.partner.company :
F0302 originator : F0302 applicability : ALL data.module.reference.code : TRENTXWBA-
00-00-00-01A01-022A-D quality.assurance : tabtop skill.level : sk01 reason.for.update : First Release
publication.code : UNKNOWN PUBLICATION

Comment: Could you try now? I assume it's due to the lack of an `fo:block`.

Comment: Hm, odd. Suppose you deleted your comment, but I changed the XSLT to include `foreign` and `unknown`. Could you please accept this answer if it helped?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Now its working good. one doubt. If the attribute value only need to appear in bold, Not the content means, how i can code in xslt?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I want the metadata information pdf output has to be attribute value as bold and content value as normal
<b>data.module.code:</b> HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D
<b>classification:</b> 01

Comment: Edited. Should give you the output you want.

Comment: No. Its not working. While im giving ur provided xslt, all appearing in normal mode without attribute.
HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D
01
F0302
F0302
ALL
TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D
tabtop
sk01
First Release
UNKNOWN PUBLICATION
001
001
2016-01-29
2016-01-29
The outputclass appearing twice. Please check and tell me

Comment: Just checked and it should work fine. See the results block in my answer to see what you should end up with. (Given your input file is still the same.)

Comment: I edited the my full set of input file. Please check it. Still not working for me

Comment: Hm. Still gives me the result you want so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Do you perhaps mean it's not bold in your PDF? In that case there's probably something else you have to do. Afraid I don't know what that is exactly.

Comment: Thank you. I will once again and tell you